# Factorial/permutations/combinations program

Tags: c#

I wrote a factorial/permutations/combinations program in Java, and I want to do the same in C#.  I noticed (from various research) that when you use the `ulong` variable type, the max value is higher than Java's `long`.  My limitation in the Java version was that the `long` type was too small to do numbers like 30, or 100.  I wrote a little thing that would test if my hypothesis that C# could stretch the range of my program, but I was proven wrong.  My Java version can reach approximately 24, but the C# goes to roughly 20.  Is there anything I can do to reach my goal?

```
using System;

namespace codeAdmiral{
  public class Factorial{
     public static void Main(){
        ulong num;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value");
        num = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ulong factorial = 1;
        for (ulong forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--){
                 factorial *= forBlockvar;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Factorial for the Given input is:");
        Console.WriteLine(factorial);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `double` if you want a greater range.

Comment: In Java, things got screwed up when i tried to use a double...  Are ulong and double interchangable like int and long in Java??

Comment: @JesseC.Slicerm Using `double` to compute precise values is not a good idea.

Comment: Not in the least. Check out these tables for what their differences are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer My point is that if you use `double`, you won't get precise results. When you're computing factorials, approximate results are usually not enough.

Comment: @svick Yes, I am well aware of that point. Unfortunately, we don't have integer types that have that range for such a computation.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer [Are you sure?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

Comment: @svick fascinating. Well there goes my productivity for the day.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Great! Another feature introduced in .NET 4.0 that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Signed 64-bit integer (`long` in both Java and C#) can have values between approximately -9 · 10<sup>18</sup> and 9 · 10<sup>18</sup>. Unsigned 64-bit integer (`ulong` in C#) can have values between 0 and approximately 1.8 · 10<sup>19</sup>. The value of 20! is approximately 2 · 10<sup>18</sup>, so it fits comfortably both to `long` and `ulong`. The value of 21! is approximately 5 · 10<sup>19</sup>, so it doesn't fit even into `ulong`.

Because of this, 20! should be computed correctly both in Java and c#, but 21! should be incorrect in both, no matter whether you use `long` or `ulong`.

If you want to make sure you are getting correct results in C#, you can use [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx). If you do that and the computation overflows, you will get an exception.

What should you do if you want to compute larger values than 20!? The best option would be if there was some type that could represent arbitrarily large integers. Fortunately, both languages have them, there is [`BigInteger` in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) and [`BigInteger` in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks!!  I have tried to use BigInteger in the Java version a while back, but that was before I understood oo programming...

Comment: The fact that factorial grows so fast makes a compelling case to store the first 20 results pre-computed in a static look-up array for practical implementation.

Comment: But that just isnt the same :)

Comment: @Leonid I don't see much reason to do that. Computing 20! is so fast that pre-computing it most likely won't speed up your code noticeably.

Comment: And it's more satisfiying to write something that computes it rather than just creating an array :)